# Error Using GoogleMaps.LocationServices to Find Latitude and Longitude in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, .net-6.0, geocode

I am looking for advice on how to get the latitude and longitude of an address using C#. I do not know how to interpret the error message I receive.

Here is my code:

```
using GoogleMaps.LocationServices;

var address = "Dallas, Texas";
var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(address);
var latitude = point.Latitude;
var longitude = point.Longitude;
```

Here is the error:

**Exception Unhandled: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).'**

I get it on line 5, `var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(address);`

For your reference, [this is the GoogleMaps.LocationServices assembly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleMaps.LocationServices).

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not identifying your API key in your location service constructor...so your request is forbidden.

```
var locationService = new GoogleLocationService(apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY");
```

See https://github.com/sethwebster/GoogleMaps.LocationServices and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key